# C++: Why can we bind elements in a vector returned by a function to non-const lvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I am new to move semantics and want to understand what's happening in this piece of code:

```cpp
vector<int> create_vector() {
    return {0, 1, 2};
}

for (int &x : create_vector()) {
    /* ... */         
}
```

If I understand correctly, the function call `create_vector()` returns an rvalue. Therefore, the elements inside it should be rvalues as well (i.e. 0, 1, 2 are rvalues). However, in the range for loop, we are binding these rvalues to a non-const lvalue reference `int &x`, which shouldn't be allowed? I thought non-const lvalue references can only bind to lvalues, not rvalues.

What's happening here? Why is this allowed?

Comment: *"Therefore, the elements inside it should be rvalues as well (i.e. 0, 1, 2 are rvalues)"* -- No.

Comment: The object (vector) returned by `create_vector()` to the caller exists until the end of the relevant statement in the calling code.   In the case of a `for` loop, the end of the statement is after completion of the loop.    Which means that, in the (incomplete) sample code give, references to its elements are valid throughout the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the Container with rvalue, but the individual elements are being returned after calling `::begin()` on the vector and then calling the `operator*()` on the returned iterator which returns a reference as you can see here:

```cpp
      // Forward iterator requirements
      _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
      reference
      operator*() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return *_M_current; }
```

If you write the for loop in the [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/) then you'll see that the for loop is calling `.begin` and then it's calling the `operator*()`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int foo() {
  int res;
  for (auto& val : vector<int>{}) {
    res += val;
  }
  return res;
}
```

[Here's the link](https://cppinsights.io/s/2699c40d) that produces this from the above example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int foo()
{
  int res;
  {
    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > && __range1 = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >{};
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; !__gnu_cxx::operator==(__begin1, __end1); __begin1.operator++()) {
      int & val = __begin1.operator*();
      res = res + val;
    }
    
  }
  return res;
}
```

Here's the [vector::begin on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin); and here's a link to [itrator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) which can be used to get the reference/pointer type of vector's iterator like this:

```cpp
using your_vector = std::vector<int>;
using vector_iterator = typename your_vector::iterator;
using traits = std::iterator_traits<vector_iterator>;
using reference_type = typename traits::reference;
using pointer_type = typename traits::pointer;
```

There are easier ways to get these types but it's the universal way for standard containers.